# HTML button click status

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to give an HTML/bootstrap button a clicked/unclicked status?  I want to be able to have the aesthetic of a button with the functionality of a checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're already using Bootstrap. If so, use their [button.js](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-single-toggle):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
  Single toggle
</button>
```

Note that this uses `aria-pressed` (read more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_button_role#Toggle_buttons)) for accessibility's sake.

Or using [`checkbox`es](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio):

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" checked> Checkbox 1 (pre-checked)
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checkbox 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checkbox 3
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a way. You can do this with pure CSS by customizing the checkbox using `labels` and `:after` like so:

**HTML**

```
<div class="button">
  <input type="checkbox" id="custom" />
  <label for="custom">Click Me</label>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.button {
    position: relative;
}

.button label {
    background: black;
    color: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    left: 4px;
    top: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 20px;
}

.button label:after {
    opacity: 0;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background: #00bf00;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #00bf00 0%, #009400 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #00bf00 0%, #009400 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #00bf00 0%, #009400 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #00bf00 0%, #009400 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #00bf00 0%, #009400 100%);
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 20px;

}

.button label:hover::after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.button input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    content: 'ACTIVE';
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/0f5d79ot/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Just create 2 CSS Classes with the different styles.

And then change the CSS-Class on JavaScript/jQuery onClick Event.

EDIT: You can use the JQuery Method .toggleClass ->     `jsfiddle.net/g1akxxg6/1/`